# How to collect coins in Unity 3D which appears randomly in the scene, destroy the Game Object after have been collected and show the score in canvas?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, tags, destroy, gameobject

I'm trying that my game character collect coins that appear randomly in the scene, trough five lanes and that the score of each coin obtained appear in the screen. Everything is running good except for one thing, after collected them, none of the coins are destroyed from the scene but the score system it seems to be working good, I really don´t know what I´m doing wrong.

The Game Object of the coin is a prefab and is being loaded by another main Game Object in the scene. There are two C# Scripts, one is for the Score Text Script and the other one is for the Coin Script. I would appreciate if someone could help me please, thanks!

Here's the code for the Coin Script:

```cs
public class CoinScript : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject PickUp;

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col)
    {
        PickUp = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("PickUp");

        if (gameObject != null)
        {
            // Do something  
            Destroy(gameObject);
            ScoreTextScript.coinAmount++;
        }  
    }
}
```

Here's the code for the Score Text Script:

```cs
public class ScoreTextScript : MonoBehaviour {

    Text text;

    public static int coinAmount;

    void Start()
    {
        text = GetComponent<Text>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        text.text = coinAmount.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: what is your CoinScript attached to? as half that code seems redundant, like finding 1 object with a tag pickup - whats that for? gameObject wont be nul unless its already destroyed. so.. if that script is on a coin, the coin will get destroyed, just not maybe immediately...

Answer (score 0):

Although your question is quite hard to read, i can propose the following solution on how to show it to the UI:

1) create an event channel object and script

Event channels are observers that will inform a class when an event happens

let's use my team's code as an example, use it as inspiration for your coins

```
namespace Game
{
    [Findable(R.S.GameObject.GameHasEndedFormallyEventChannel)]
    public class GameHasEndedFormallyEventChannel : EventChannel
    {
        public event EventHandler OnGameEnded;

        public override void Publish()
        {
            if (OnGameEnded != null)
            {
                OnGameEnded();
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

The event handler is used on classes where they will "subscribe" to the event and wait for a signal. The method Publish is for the ones who will inform the subscribed classes of the event.

Don't forget to add it to a GameObject (preferably accessible to all other gameobject scripts)

Now in the class where it detects the player collides with a coin, instantiate the EventChannel by finding it's gameObject and call the method publish() right after the collision.

On the UI class, add the following code (don't forget to find the event channel in this class as well):

```
 private void OnEnable()
        {
            playerGainedScoreEventChannel.OnCoinGained += YourMethodToUpdateScore;
        }
```

and in the method to update the score, you can do something like:

```
score++    
scoreUI.text = score.ToString()
```

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

As Adrian said in spite if codeamount works the Destroy call should work too.
Are you sure at your prefab, the gameObject your are destroying (the gameObject where the script is placed) is the same than the whole coin?

This is an example of this code little cleaned:

```
public class CoinScript : MonoBehaviour {

    //You don't use it, at least at OntriggerEnter, so you might not need it
    //public GameObject PickUp; 

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col)

        //You don't use this at this method PickUp at this method
        //PickUp = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("PickUp");

        //gameobject is never null if it's not destroyed, u dont need this if.
        //if (gameObject != null)

        //if you want to be sure only PickUp gameObject is able to collect the coin you can do this
        if(col.gameObject.tag == "PickUp")
        {
            // Do something  
            ScoreTextScript.coinAmount++;
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below are the scripts using C#

Coin script

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Coins : MonoBehaviour {

    void Start () {}
    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        Debug.Log("Triggered");
        Destroy(gameObject);
        scorescript.scorevalue += 3;
    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
}
}
```

Score Script

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class scorescript : MonoBehaviour {
    public static int scorevalue = 0;
    Text score1;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        score1 = GetComponent<Text>();
    }
// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
        score1.text = "score : " + scorevalue;
    }
}
```